# Why can't I mv a file?

Tags: macos, permissions, osx-lion, mv

I followed these instructions to remove Java from my Mac (Lion): http://stikine.wordpress.com/2012/03/02/howto-remove-java/ As part of the procedure, I needed to edit the file /Library/Receipts/InstallHistory.plist

I followed these steps:

1. `sudo bash` (supplied password)
2. `cp /Library/Receipts/InstallHistory.plist ~/Desktop`
3. `chown userx:staff ~/Desktop/InstallHistory.plist` (I'm userx, permissions were -rw-r--r--  1 root  admin)
4. edited `~/Desktop/InstallHistory.plist` and closed
5. `chown root:wheel ~/Desktop/InstallHistory.plist`

All was well until the final step (#5):

```
mv ~/Desktop/InstallHistory.plist /Library/Receipt/
```

which produced the message:

```
mv: rename /Users/caryswoveland/Desktop/InstallHistory.plist to /Library/Receipt/: No such file or directory
```

I don't know a great deal about Unix.

What's the problem?

Comment: a chown operation is NOT going to produce a 'rename' error...

Comment: Why did you have to do step 3 if you were `sudo` into `bash`? And did you do a Ctrl-D before you did the `mv` that gave you the error?

Comment: @mbratch per the instructions linked, step 4 was with a gui editor, hence permission change... but yes, would have been so much easier to just sudo vim, and make the changes.

Comment: Are you sure the file exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You copied from:

- `/Library/Receipts`

You tried (but failed) to copy to:

- `/Library/Receipt/`

Try adding the missing `s`.

Comment: That will do it every time.  I just copied that, missing s and all.  Thanks.

Comment: Be grateful you copied the trailing slash.  Without that, you'd have had a file `/Library/Receipt` and the original version of the file `/Library/Receipts/InstallHistory.plist`, and that would lead to further confusion down the road.  And let he who has never made a similar mistake cast the first stone — and when that stone is lobbed, I'll show you a rank novice programmer.  Nevertheless, I don't think this Q&A is going to be a lot of help to future users.